# @angular/fire and RxJS: Return value from rxjs pipe/map

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, angularfire2, angularfire

I want this function to return the value of id but I'm not able to figure out where to give the return statement.

```
findCardId(card) {
  this.afs.collection('cards', ref=>ref.where('title', '==', `${card.title}`)).snapshotChanges().pipe(
   first(),
   map(actions => { actions.map(a => {
    const id = a.payload.doc.id;
   })})
  ).subscribe();
}
```

Comment: so you want to return one id or all ids from `actions` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to return `id` from your map where you have assigned to id variable and then you need to return this function result as `observable` so that you can subscribe in your component and get return there.

**your.service.ts**

```
findCardId(card) : Observable<any> {
      return this.afs.collection('cards', ref=>ref.where('title', '==', `${card.title}`)).snapshotChanges().pipe(
       first(),
       map(actions => { 
          return actions.map(a => {
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return id;
       })})
      )
    }
```

**your.component.ts**

```
 constructor(private myService : MyService) { }
  getCardId() {
   this.myService.findCardId(card).subscribe( id => {
       console.log(id)// here is your id
   }     
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Got this working by adding a return statement before actions.map.

Answer (score 1):

Right now your inner `map` function (the one that operates on the `actions` array) doesn't return anything.

If you're trying to return an array with all the `id`s from the `actions` array, you can simply do it like this

```
...
map(actions => actions.map(a => a.payload.doc.id))
...
```